# UICollectionView as the HEADER of the APPLICATION in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, header, uicollectionview

I want to set a `UICollectionView` as the HEADER of the APPLICATION. Please see the below the image :-

[image]

In this image, I have to add a collection view in the red oval area. There are almost 15-20 options. And I have to open different viewcontroller from all the options.

Is there any way to add a UICollectionView as the HEADER of the APPLICATION.?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you using uitableview to list below options?

Comment: Right now I have added that collection view in all the view controllers. So I want to make it global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, Got the solution !! Thanks @Tushar, for help me to Findout the solution.

I have just create one controller. And In that controller, I have added `UICollectionView` on the header. And before that, added one `UIView`.

Now, when we tap on the collection view, I have create the object of the other controller, which I wish to add below. And added that view as a child view. Please refer the following code :-

```
FirstViewController *firstViewObj = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:firstViewObj];
firstViewObj.view.frame=myContentView.bounds;
[myContentView addSubview:firstViewObj.view];
[firstViewObj didMoveToParentViewController:self];
//[firstViewObj willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
```

Please download the [Demo Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ya2gnumndduj3xk/ViewControllerDemo.zip?dl=0) for more details.

Hope, this is what you're looking for. Any concern get back to me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need guidance on the view controller architecture and UI setup. I would suggest following for a quick setup:

MainViewController, containing following views -

- CollectionView as Header
- ContentViewController's view as subview (added as childViewController), having the table/UI and data specific to the type passed to it from parent view controller (when a type is selected from collection view).

The MainViewController manages the selection of options from collection and sets up the content view controller based on that.

You can use different view controllers as ContentViewController if your UI is different for different header option/type or use same class but different instance if the UI is same.